# I need advice on how to best handle an e-commerce situation

Tags: encryption, security, payment-gateway, credit-card

I recently moved to Brazil and started a small subscription based service company. The payment gateway market is under-developed in Brazil, and implementing a local solution is too expensive for me.

My requirements are a payment gateway that will automatically process monthly recurrent billing, and that will allow me to manually charge my customers when needed. They would also have to deal with storage and security.

I'm leaning towards manually processing payments myself as a restaurant would do, for example, using small swipe machines. Unfortunately, this would require me to store credit card information and I would rather not, but I feel it's my only option.

Can anyone give me advice on how to tackle this problem?

- What are my options?
- Is my idea a good idea, or a terrible idea?
- If I decide to store credit card information, what should I keep in mind and how should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many payment processors out there - not sure what the options are in Brazil, but here in Europe we can use Paypal (great becuase everyone knows it) or others such as [RealEx](http://www.realexpayments.com).

The advice I would give - from my own experience taking payments on a busy betting website - is to go for a solution that means *you do not have to store credit card numbers* if you can. It's so much easier for everyone. Ideally all processing should happen on the provider's website so that no personal info (such as credit card numbers etc.) is required on your site. This approach means you sometimes do not even need an SSL certificate. It's safe, and the customer likes it because they know the trusted middle man (e.g. Paypal).

If you *have* to integrate a payment method such as credit card into your side and it means that you are going to be requesting and storing this information on your website then you need to ensure your site is secure and **this is a not an easy thing**.

- You will need to ensure that you
  network is secure
- You will need to
  make sure your code is secure (SQL
  injection for example)
- You will need
  to make sure you use SSL for all
  server to server comms
- You will need
  to encrypt (AES 256 I'd recommend)
  your credit card numbers (if you have
  to store them - remember you could
  just use them in that session and do
  not persist them to the database!)

It's is complicated, and it takes time. You can look into PCI compliance down the road (depending on volume you might be forced to by the processor!) but for now if at all possible use a third party website for payments.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the information. PayPal would have been perfect accept they don't offer their top-tier, fully integrated business account. The one they offer requires users to register and manage their own subscriptions, which represents a massive operation risk for me.